# unable to use Material Theme

Tags: android, material-design

My first app with Material Design, So I am trying to use the Material Theme, however can't use it. When I type in `@android:style/Theme.Material.Light` its underlined red.

Even my SDK is 21, So can't figure why I am unable to use it.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "obx.com.futurister"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: You are setting a minSdkVersion of 17

Comment: Yes, is that a reason?

Comment: Material Theme is available in API 21. You can't use it in API 17. There's a AppCompat  theme that's available in support library that will work on older version as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to support older SDK versions, you can use the AppCompat library in the support repository.

In your themes.xml file, you can then do the following:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base" />

     <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
       <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
       <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
       <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>

       <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
       <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>

    </style>

</resources>
```

Then you can simply reference this theme in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks for the support

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the minSDKVersion to 17.

The [Support Library](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html) lets you sue new features added into android on devices with older versions of android. You should look into it (especial v7 since thats related to Material Design)!